# JavaScript HTML graphics (with vertices)

Tags: javascript, html, graphics

Is there any way to create basic 2D shapes in HTML besides rectangles and circles, using JavaScript?

For example, let's say we have a `<canvas></canvas>` (because any other element can't be modified the way I'm trying, or?) element, with `width:100px`, `height:300px` and `background:black`.
How can I move it's top-right corner (top right vertex) to a different position to create a different shape then a rectangle?

From:

```
point one:   x: 0px   / y: 0px
point two:   x: 100px / y: 0px
point three: x: 100px / y: 300px
point four:  x: 0px   / y: 300px
```

To:

```
point one:   x: 0px   / y: 0px
point two:   x: 120px / y: -20px
point three: x: 100px / y: 300px
point four:  x: 0     / y:300px
```

(`point two` is the one changed)

Is there any JavaScript graphics library for HTML that would make this a simple task? Something along the line of `drawable.vertices[1].move(20, -20)` to move the second vertex 20px on x and -20 px on y.

Comment: Do you want just library? I recomend use SVG with any JS framework (i.e. jQuery), but it's more difficult.

Comment: Since I only find heavy-duty libraries, I could do it myself, but I can't figure out how to access one of the vertices to move around. Or if there even is such a thing as vertices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you taken a look at pixi.js? (http://www.pixijs.com/) it is a 2d library which utilizes WebGL but falls back to canvas if WebGL is not supported by the browser. If you want to go to 3d libraries also look into Three.js (http://threejs.org/)

Another fairly popular graphics library specifically for canvas is the Raphael library (http://raphaeljs.com/)

**Update**:

To initialize a canvas with Raphael in an element with an offset of 100px and with dimensions of 300x300px. Take note that I have a dependency on JQuery here to get the "mycanvas" element.

```
var paper = Raphael($("#mycanvas"), 100, 300,300);
```

To draw an arbitrary polygon you need to use the path function that is on the Raphael "paper" object passing in the svg path string (if you are interested in reading more on the SVG path standard you can find some info here: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData)

```
paper.path("M150,0L200,100L100,100Z").attr("fill","#F00");
```

The attribute at the end off the path fills the polygon with red.

In two lines I have generated a red triangle using SVG paths. More lightweight than that I don't think you are going to get.

Now based on your last comment you want this to be interactive. This is not going to be as simple as you think.

A rough method for what you are trying to achieve will require you to:

1) keep an array of vertices that you are going to transform into an SVG string.

2) You are going to have to keep track of mouse down events on the canvas. Each time you find a mouse down event you are going to have to check to see if it is over a vertex in your vertex list, it would be  wise to add an epsilon for error so that the user doesn't have to click exactly on a pixel but rather in an area close to vertex. You can use a boxing method to give you some sort of box epsilon around the point of the vertex. Create a reference to the vertex you are having the mouse down.

3) On the mouse move event while the mouse button is also down and there is an active vertex you want to modify the position of that vertex based on the mouse coordinates.

4) On the mouse up event and depending on how many vertices you have in your polygon you may be able to just clear the paper with paper.clear() and redraw the path by generating the new SVG path string from your vertex list and using paper.path(...) adding your new SVG string.

Here is a link to the plnkr that I created to draw the triangle polygon for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/AK5zO1ZqBTerMf9AzS88?p=preview

**FINAL BONUS UPDATE:**

So I decided to do this for you in plnkr so you can see how to manipulate the paths and force a redraw. Essentially the javascript draws two paths one for the triangle and one for the blue dots at the end of each triangle vertex. I registered two delegate functions in the drag of the control path elements so that each one of them can update their X and Y values as well as the corresponding triangle vertex. Take a look at the plnkr and let me know if something doesn't make sense.

http://plnkr.co/edit/o5QHap7NV1SYIbsS76f5

Enjoy! :)

Comment: Both of them are way overkill. I only want to do a basic 2D shape with n vertices that can be moved around independently. If there is no easy to use library, how would I go about doing it myself?

Comment: That is exactly what path does in raphael. Add the fill attribute to make it solid. http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.path You just need to use the M and L SVG commands in the path, refer to the documentation in the link I sent you. When I get to the office I will try to whip up a plnkr for you.

Comment: And how can I change any of the points' position after the object is created? I can't figure that out.

Comment: I might have understood how `canvas` works incorrectly. I'm thinking that the canvas itself is modifiable (it's vertexes can be moved around), but it seems that I should draw objects inside it.

Comment: Yes you did misunderstand the canvas. Interactivity will cost you some effort. Putting in the effort will definitely be rewarding! I have updated my post to include an example of using the path function on Raphael paper. I hope the explanation of how to add the interactivity you want is concise and easy to follow.

Comment: I get it now. `canvas` itself can't be interactive, it can't change something, but it can destroy and recreate it based on new data. Thank you, this answer is awesome.

Comment: I gave this a little thought today and decided to come up with a working interactive example using Raphael. Personally I think it didn't require too much code. Try not to drag the control out of the canvas frame because I didn't limit it from moving outside. Take a look at it and let me know if this is satisfactory or if anything is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I did some polygon stuff in the gamecanvas.  I made functions to produce somewhat arbitrary polygons, positioned relative to a camera / player position, that might be relevant or helpful (from my open sauce javascript learning project [Umo Space](https://github.com/kanethemediocre/umospace)).  The key takeaways here are that you pick a color with

```
context.fillstyle = "red";//then

context.beginpath(); //to start the polygon, then use 

context.moveto(x,y); //to pick a starting vertex (x and y are numbers), and 

context.lineto(x,y);// to select more vertices from there (at least 3 points to a polygon).  You don't need to return to the first vertex at the end, just use 

context.fill(); //and it will automagically close the polygon and fill it with the color.
```

```
        function drawpolarpoly(px,py,thetalist, radiuslist, size, color, dir){
    //requires, does not verify, that thetalist.length==radiuslist.length, thetalist.length>2, color be valid
        var fx = px + Math.cos(dir+thetalist[0])*size*radiuslist[0];
        var fy = py + Math.sin(dir+thetalist[0])*size*radiuslist[0];
        context.fillStyle = color; //Now actual drawing of the things
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(fx, fy); 
        i = thetalist.length;
        while(i>0){
            i=i-1;
            var ix = px + Math.cos(dir+thetalist[i])*size*radiuslist[i];
            var iy = py + Math.sin(dir+thetalist[i])*size*radiuslist[i];
            context.lineTo(ix, iy);
        }
        context.fill(); 
    }
    function draworthopoly(px,py, xlist, ylist, size, color, dir){//Not really useful, because this
        var fx = px + xlist[0]*size; //needs to be transformed to polar coords to rotate it anyways
        var fy = py + ylist[0]*size;
        context.fillStyle = color; //Now actual drawing of the things
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(fx, fy); 
        i = xlist.length;
        while(i>0){
            i=i-1;
            var ix = px + xlist[i]*size;
            var iy = py + ylist[i]*size;
            context.lineTo(ix, iy);
        }
        context.fill(); 
        }
```